# What is the name of a suction cup + carabiner? How to find these?

Tags: travel-tools

Looking for a useful travel suction cup to hang accessories/bath bags but can't find it no matter what words I use to search for it. Here below are a couple of pictures of what am looking for:

[image]

[image]

It can be simply described as a **Suction Cup and Carabiner** like this at this link https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08B6B5WKQ. However, I am not looking to buy this whole amazon item that has extra stuff, I am just looking for the suction cup with carabiner.

I tried the following search terms, but no matter how I try it seems impossible to be found:

- Suction Cup + Carabiner
- Suction Cup And Carabiner
- Suction Cup With Carabiner
- Suction Cup Sucker
- Suction Cup Sucker with hole and carabiner

How can I find what am looking for? All the results are far from what am looking for. See below pictures for what I am NOT looking for:

[image]

Any help on search terms on how to find this or links to purchasable items would be very appreciated.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145289/discussion-on-question-by-fed-what-is-the-name-of-a-suction-cup-carabiner-how); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.